# OpenLayers map not showing on Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, openlayers

I have a search results screen showing 10 results (locations in the world) per page. If a result has an image available, the image will show, otherwise it shows the location on an OpenLayers map.

I'm just trying to upgrade this page using Bootstrap carousel to allow users to cycle between the map and the image (if available).

I got carousel working fine using 2 test images. However when I swap in the OL map, although the image/photo shows OK, when you cycle to the next item (the map), the map just shows a white screen / nothing shows.

Code is below. (FYI the map works fine when I pull it out of the carousel code.

Any ideas?

Happy to share the Ol.map code, although as mentioned it runs OK outside of carousel, so I assume it might be some sort of formatting/CSS issue.

```
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <%= image_tag(@phototouse, class:"map img-responsive", style:"display:block;height: 100%;max-height:350px") %>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div id="<%= location.location_id %>" class="map" style="display:block;height: 100%;max-height:350px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls<%= location.location_id %>" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls<%= location.location_id %>" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Update:

I thought I had got this working by adding in the updateSize event (below) but weirdly the map only shows when I resize the window. If I don't touch the window, the map doesn't show and I get the following java error: 'map1.updateSize is not a function'.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="container-fluid normaltextblack"  style="background-color: #F3F3F3;">

  <div class="row" style="height:350px">

    <div id="sidel" class="col-0 col-sm-0 col-md-0 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">

      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/image1.jpg" alt="First slide" style="height:350px">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div id="testmap" class="map img-responsive" style="height:350px"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev"  onclick="resizemap();">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next"  onclick="resizemap();">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
            
  function resizemap() {

      setTimeout(function(){ 
        
        var map1 = document.getElementById("testmap");
      map1.updateSize();

      }, 1000); 

  }
            
</script>
```

Comment: You may need to call `map.updateSize()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize when the carousel switches to the map.

Comment: Any ideas on my updateSize issue?